# How do I add a Doctrine filter in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, filter, doctrine-orm

I am adding a [filter](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html) for Doctrine 2 in a Symfony 2 project.  Following the [document](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html) I have created the filter class and put it under MyVendor\MyProjectBundle\Filter\MyFilter.php.  What is the better way to do the configuration ane disabling/enabling bits as in the document?  I do not know how to access the config object for Doctrine 2 in Symfony.  Also if the filter is to be enabled globally, are there ways to do this without changingi every controller?

Answer (score 10):

Search for the `filter` word in the [Doctrine bundle configuration reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html).

The example from the doc looks like this:

> ```
> doctrine:
>     orm:
>         filters:
>             myFilter:
>                 class: MyVendor\MyBundle\Filters\MyFilter
>                 enabled: true
>                 parameters:
>                     myParameter: myValue
>                     mySecondParameter: mySecondValue
> ```

Comment: Umm, just curious: does this work in Symfony 2.0?  The option is missing in the [reference for 2.0](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/doctrine.html).

Comment: No, it's not available in Symfony 2.0.